# Javascript RegEx adding a comma on results

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to do a simple RegEx match as below:

```
var page = "<title>Hello, World!</title>";
var pattern = /<title>(.*?)<\/title>/i;
var title = pattern.exec(page);
document.write(title);
```

For some reason, the results look like:

```
,Hello, World!
```

Any idea why the comma is being added to the start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pattern.exec()` returns an array.  The first item in the returned array is the entire match.  The second item in the returned array is the first matched group.  You're calling `document.write()` on an array of two elements, not on a single string.  Array entries are separated by commas when output in many circumstances.  You don't see the first item in the array because it's this HTML `<title>Hello, World!</title>` which is invisible.  Then, there's a comma between that element and the next element which is the text you want.

Your code should probably be this:

```
var page = "<title>Hello, World!</title>";
var pattern = /<title>(.*?)<\/title>/i;
var match = pattern.exec(page);
if (match) {
    document.write(match[1]);
}
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BQ33Q/